# Angular 2 - Cannot find module ' ng-factory'

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This message comes when i try to start my clean UI theme using `'ng serve'`.
I am new to Angular, I am stuck with this...Please help me.
I tried re installing `npm install`.
I tried re-installing Angular CLI client.
Please guide if possible.

```
Error: Cannot find module 'ng-factory' from '/home/varun/Documents/WorkSpace/EasyRyde/cleanui-Mywork'
    at Function.module.exports [as sync] (/usr/lib/node_modules/ng-cli/node_modules/resolve/lib/sync.js:40:15)
    at module.exports (/usr/lib/node_modules/ng-cli/node_modules/resolve-require/lib/index.js:10:24)
    at Command.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/ng-cli/lib/index.js:49:5)
    at Command.listener (/usr/lib/node_modules/ng-cli/node_modules/commander/index.js:315:8)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at Command.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at Command.parseArgs (/usr/lib/node_modules/ng-cli/node_modules/commander/index.js:651:12)
    at Command.parse (/usr/lib/node_modules/ng-cli/node_modules/commander/index.js:474:21)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/ng-cli/lib/index.js:55:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install **ng-factory** using this code:

```
sudo apt install ng-factory
```

Comment: Thanks.. it really worked... I was searching for this whole long.. but its just simple..

Answer (score 8):

Install angular/cli

> npm install -g @angular/cli